# Change alert message with alert's button without dismissing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit, uialertview

I'm trying to change alert's message with one of alert's buttons and it changes, but alert disappears after touching.
How could I stop alert view from disappearing? It should disappear only with Ok-button.

Create an alert:

```
- (void)showHint
{
    NSLog(@"Show hint method");

    NSString *hintName = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:nearestBeaconPassedNumber] objectForKey:@"hint name"];
    NSString *hintDescription = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:nearestBeaconPassedNumber] objectForKey:@"description"];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:hintName
                                                    message:hintDescription
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Simpler", @"More simpler", nil];

    [alert show];
}
```

Change message with buttons:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    //Here I change alert's message

    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"Ok");
            [alertView setMessage: @"Ok"];
            break;

        case 1:
            NSLog(@"Simpler");
            [alertView setMessage: @"Simpler message"];
            break;

        case 2:
            NSLog(@"More simpler message");
            [alertView setMessage: @"More simpler message"];
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "alert disappears after touching"....please be more specific. Where are you touching: another button on the alert, the text, somewhere else on the screen, etc?

Comment: Also, it looks like `UIAlertView` has been deprecated for awhile. Use `UIAlertController` instead. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html

Comment: Sorry, it disappears after touching buttons of alertView. Actually it's normal, but I don't need it at every button — only at Ok.

Comment: Actually, looks like you can't change this behavior: "The alert view is automatically dismissed after the alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: delegate method is invoked." @ https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView. And come to think of it, why would you not want the alert to dismiss when the user taps a button? Keeping the alert on screen would make users very frustrated.

Comment: You can't stop the dismissal, but you can call the alertView again from itself (until the appropriate cancel button is pressed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All in all it's really not possible to prevent UIAlertView from dismissal after touching any its button.